# Permission denied for another user in git when using https

Tags: git, ssh

I am getting an error when trying to push to a repository I own saying:

`remote: Permission to my_user_name/my_repo.git denied to another_user_name.`

I have regenerated the SSH keys and remove the old ones from both my machine and Github. I also see in `gitconfig --list` that my email is correct.

What can be happening? This just happens when trying to push via https instead of using the SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using HTTPS, mangling with SSH keys has no effect at all, because you are not using SSH but HTTPS. It seems you used https with `another_user_name` before and have some credential helper that remembers this.  See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials for more information about this.